# catkin generating lib packages instead of bin packages

Tags: ros, catkin-package, catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all;

I am starting with ROS, groovy version.
I have managed to compile some code in a package using catkin, but the executables generated are placed ~/catkin_ws/devel/lib/package_name.

In my CmakeLists.txt I have used "add_executable" and "target_link_libraries"

I think the executables should be in ~/catkin_ws/devel/bin/package_name., instead under lib directory.

Is this correct? Where could I have the error?

Thank you all in advance,

Best Regards,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62766/catkin-generating-lib-packages-instead-of-bin-packages/) by [altella](https://answers.ros.org/users/4898/altella/) on ROS Answers with karma: 149 on 2013-05-15

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

AFAIK this is correct and not an error at your side, although a bit ugly.

My guess is that this is used to not pollute the namespace in $PATH that adds bin/... and only run nodes via `rosrun`. A comment from the developers would be nice.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-05-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-05-15**:
Not a developer, but I've been documenting catkin lately. Here's my current draft, which agrees with your answer: http://farnsworth.csres.utexas.edu/docs/catkin/html/howto/building_executables.html#installing

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-05-15**:
For an official answer, see REP-0122: http://ros.org/reps/rep-0122.html